# Swift Present Function, Background Coloring Dark Mode

Tags: ios, swift, view, background-color

I am attempting to add a dark mode to my app and I have it almost done but I am having trouble with this one piece. When I call

```
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

my image below pops up in front of my previous view. However, the top coloring is white still instead of dark. I have tried numerous different background color changes but can't seem to find the correct layer to change the background on. Does anyone know what layer this is to so I can change it to black to complete my dark mode?

[image: View image on present popover]

Answer (score 0):

Although that should be `black` by default, it's `window`'s background view. So you can change it to any color you want:

```
view.window?.backgroundColor = .yellow
```

[image: demo]

**Note that** you can use `.systemBackground` as color. so it's automatically the correct color in either light or dark mode.

And also **note that** the window color only needs to be set once (per window). Set it in the App/Scene delegate and be done

---

<sub>All views have access to their window</sub>

<sub>Thanks to **@rmaddy** for the notes</sub>

Comment: You should `.systemBackground` so it's automatically the correct color in either light or dark mode.

Comment: Also note that the window color only needs to be set once. Set it in the App/Scene delegate and be done.

Comment: Thanx for reminding of that @rmaddy . Added to answer